# Так у меня есть массив,на массиве string элементы, нужно конверт на integer

Tags: php

***Вот например у меня такой массив***
**Язык - php**

```
$arr = array("10,100,100,10,10");
```

*Сейчас мне нужно чтобы элементы стали integer и, как это реализовать? помогите пожалуйста разобратся.*

**Массив нужен в таком виде(чтобы мне вернул цифры а не стринг)**

```
$arr = array(10,100,100,10,10);
```

Comment: Парсите строчку по запятым, конвертируя например `"10"` в целое число.

Comment: `array_map('intval', explode(',', $arr[0]))`

Comment: Спасибо большое помог